# How do I cancel a schedule for a task?

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I need to create a scheduled task. For that I'm trying to learn how to do that, and am currently thinking of using `TaskSchedulerClass` from TaskScheduler Class Library. I got a code examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3362800/939213) (and there's another one I might try [here](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/23/calling-the-task-scheduler-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008-from-managed-code.aspx)). But - I don't want to actually run it without making sure I know how to cancel it when needed.

So my question is: How do I cancel such a task-registration in code?

(Just "Try it!" won't suffice in this case. Because the point is I don't want to get stuck with something I can't stop.)

Answer (score 2):

What about [TryDequeue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.trydequeue.aspx)?

It's attempts to dequeue a Task that was previously queued to this scheduler.

You need to use the same Task you sent to [QueueTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.queuetask) function.

If you don't have the instance of this Task you can try and retrieve it using [GetScheduledTasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.getscheduledtasks), but it stated it in use `For debugger support only`

Comment: Thanks. (It took me some time, until I figured out that Intellisense doesn't show it, and that I have to add the whole namespace before it...) Anyway, how do I find the task? I assume I can't just create a new task and cancel it.

Comment: But I'll want to cancel it in a separate run of my code. Will it not simply create a _new_ task and cancel _that_?

Comment: Right. That's why I removed it from my comment. So am still looking for a solution.

Comment: I'm getting "... TaskScheduler.TryDequeue...is inaccessible due to its protection level". Any ideas?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer for lack of a better one. But I'm still interested in an answer.