# How to do a timed SQL server login?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

Here is my problem , I am coding a C#  application that will log in to a remote **SQL server 2008 [Express edition to be precise]** and fetch data from the database table (say foo) periodically[after each fetch the SQL client connection is closed ] .

How can I do this process periodically with a time interval like 60 seconds or so (user definable). ??

Comment: I would use a Timer.

[How do you add a timer to a c-sharp console application][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186084/how-do-you-add-a-timer-to-a-c-sharp-console-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `System.Threading.Timer` I'd use `System.Timers.Timer` which can be configured to be a "one shot" timer using the `AutoReset` property:

```
System.Timers.Timer sqlTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
sqlTimer.Interval = 60000; // One minute
sqlTimer.AutoReset = false; // Fire only once
sqlTimer.Elapsed = TimerEvent; // Assign event for timer
sqlTimer.Start(); // Start the timer
```

In that case, as the timer fires only once, you don't need to worry about locking or synchronization:

```
private void TimerEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your SQL-stuff

    // Restart the timer if you want
    sqlTimer.Start();
}
```

It must be noted that this timer as well runs in a separate thread, so the `TimerEvent` event will not be called in the context of the thread that created the timer. This is important to know in case you need to update any UI elements.

Please note that this does not work for .NET Compact Framework, as it doesn't know the `System.Timers` namespace - you'll have to use Richard's solution in that case.

Comment: Yup your solution is more apt in my case , anyways I have tested the Richard's solution and  it works fine .Thanks Richard and Thorsten +1 for both :)

Answer (score 1):

> with a time interval like 60 seconds or so

60s is rather less then things like Windows Task Scheduler is set up for – it can do it via the advanced settings (once per day and repeat every one minute.

One open question is what to do if a run of the task takes longer than the scheduler interval? Can two runs overlap or not? Assuming they can overlap something as simple as:

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(method, null, 
                                       TimeSpan.Zero, // Start now.
                                       TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

where `method` is a delegate of type [`TimerCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback.aspx): takes an `object` *state* (`null` passed above) and returns nothing.

If you do not want to allow calls to overlap should the next task be skipped or delayed, assuming skipped:

```
var object locker = new object();
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => {
  bool entered = Monitor.TryEnter(locker);
  try {
    if (entered) {
      method(null);
    }
  } finally {
     if (entered) {
       Monitor.Exit(locker);
     }
  }
},  null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

(where, again, `method` is the worker code).

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the built in schedulers within SQL Server Agent, or the one built into Windows? Why reinvent the wheel?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx)

> **Benefits of SQL Server Agent** SQL Server Agent uses SQL Server to store job information. Jobs contain one or more job steps. Each step
>   contains its own task, for example, backing up a database.
>
> SQL Server Agent can run a job on a schedule, in response to a
>   specific event, or on demand. For example, if you want to back up all
>   the company servers every weekday after hours, you can automate this
>   task. Schedule the backup to run after 22:00 Monday through Friday; if
>   the backup encounters a problem, SQL Server Agent can record the event
>   and notify you.

Or see this :

[Is it possible to use Windows 7 Task scheduler in own application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359406/is-it-possible-to-use-windows-7-task-scheduler-in-own-application)

or

[How might I schedule a C# Windows Service to perform a task daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503564/how-might-i-schedule-a-c-sharp-windows-service-to-perform-a-task-daily)

Comment: Thanks for replying ,I agree SQL Server Agent can be used for scheduling but the SQL server itself is residing on a separate machine and I don't want to mess around with it.I don't want OS depended scheduling features included into the client.

Comment: Ask yourself how portable your app is. Are you coding for multiple platforms or will you be running just on windows? If you are only targeting one OS then you're app is already dependent on that OS.

Comment: I just want to keep  server interaction minimal and client code to be portable across different Windows versions .My question is by using the native scheduler will it complicate the portability.I do agree that task schedulers and System.Timers are two possible solutions but which one is the best ??

Comment: @PreetSangha SQL Server Agent isn't available in SQL Express anyway, and even if it was it isn't clear how a scheduled job on the server would be able to push data to a client.

Comment: I don't get how the Server Agent should help select the data within a C# application...